# How do I fix this circular dependency?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, dependency-management

I'm in the unit testing/test-driven development section of *Adaptive Code via C#* by Gary McLean Hall. My question is based on an example in the book that may contain an error. Here is what the UML diagram looks like for an example `AccountService` in a 3-layered architecture:

[image: UML Diagram]

I have my solution split up into four different projects that correspond with the layers: User_Interface, Business_Logic, Data_Access, and Unit_Tests.

My question relates to the `IAccountRepository` interface. In the book the author writes the following code for a fake class (in the Unit_Tests project) used to mock an implementation of the `IAccountRepository` interface for use with the unit tests:

```
class FakeAccountRepository : IAccountRepository
{    
   private Account account;

   public FakeAccountRepository(Account account)
   {
       this.account = account;
   }

   public Account GetByName(string accountName)
   {
       return account;
   }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the `GetByName()` method returns an `Account` type. If I try to change the signature in `IAccountRepository` to have an `Account` return type, it cannot find the type. Since the `Account` class is part of the Business Logic layer, if I try to add a reference to the Business_Logic project (from the Data_Access project), Visual Studio gives me a "circular dependency" error.

[image: circular dependency error]

That makes sense because the Data Access Layer is the bottom layer and should not depend on any layers above itself...but without the reference I cannot have an `Account` return type in the `IAccountRepository` interface.

Did the author just forget something? Should I make an `IAccount` interface, change the `GetByName()` method to return an `IAccount` type, and have `Account` implement the `IAccount` interface? If not, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possibilities here:

1. **Add a project named "Common"** or something like that - store there the Account class, and add the reference to Common in both **Data Access** and **Business Logic** projects
2. **Create two classes for Account**: one in Data Access, and one in Business Logic. Both will have the same fields (properties). The second class should be name AccountModel.
   This is the approach which I've seen in professional solutions. Basically, Data Access layer has entity classes and Business Logic layer has model classes. When service fetches data from repository, it maps the object of type Account to an object of type AccountModel

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would adding a reference to the "Common" project not create a dependency on it? I'm trying to learn the best practices and the book specifically mentions that the DAL should be able to stand on its own without the other layers. Layers above the DAL depend on the DAL, but the DAL cannot depend on the layers above it. Because of this I'm more inclined to go towards option 2. Do you think this is what the author intended and accidentally left out?

Comment: The option 2 seems better choice - as you have mentioned, it makes the DAL a standalone, functional package. The "Common" project kind of messes things up, so I wouldn't really use it - it's there to point out the advantages of the second approach.

And about what the author indented to - I can only guess. Maybe he wanted reader to fixx it himself, of as @Robert mentioned below - the author could have put everything in one project, but different namespaces. And I think that's fine for a demo, educational purposes.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible that the author was writing this as a single executable and had everything in a single project so the data access layer had visibility to the account class.

You could do this yourself and simply separate the "layers" into different namespaces to provide logical separation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The chapters prior to the one this example is in goes through the best practices of multi-layered architecture / dependency management and how each layer should be in its own assembly. This is a major theme of the book. Due to this, I don't think the author did it all in one project...

Comment: Also, how would separating the app into namespaces instead of projects fix the fact that the DAL would still need to have a dependency on the Business Logic layer which goes against the principle that the DAL should not depend on any layers above itself?

Comment: This is where theory hits practical application.  You're going to have to choose between duplicating code (creating an Account class for each project) and creating a shared library that contains code that is shared between the different layers.  This is a common issue with micro-services architecture.  EDIT:  Creating a shared library would create a dependency, but it would allow for independent assemblies.  Duplicate classes will allow for independent assemblies, but make managing code changes more difficult.

Comment: In this kind of architecture, the repository layer should have its own DTOs. The business layer would then transform is Business Object (Account) into Repository AccountDto when writing/reading. You can use a library like automapper to avoid writting the tedious translation code. This is a downside of this kind of architetcure. So you are just missing an AccountDto in your IAccountRepository. Once you have that you can remove the dependency to your BL.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a different approach than the answers here. I made an interface called `IAccount` in the Data Access Layer and used `IAccount` as the return type for the `GetByName()` method. This resolved my problem and still maintained the layered architecture.